# Why is this statement of a limit not necessarily true?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

I feel as though I understand the solution of (b) [algebraic manipulation correct?]

But what is going on with (a)? What is the brace trying to convey? Where does the 5 come from? Why is one not equal to zero but the other is? Does this have anything to do with the conditions of the quotient law of limits?

Thank you

Comment: That notation means that $f(x) = x$ if $x \neq 0$, and $f(x) = 5$ if $x = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The braces denote a piecewise expression; $5$ could be replaced by any non-zero number. The point of this exercise is that the limit says nothing about the value of the function **at** the point being approached; it only deals with behaviour in a neighbourhood of that point.

Comment: How does this question illustrate its purpose through this hypothetical then? I’m lost. Very sorry.

Comment: @user312484 If you try to draw a physical graph where $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x=1$, you will invariably get a function where $f(0)=0$. You might be tempted to think then that this is always true - the counterexample is intended to show otherwise. $f(0)=0$ is true if $f$ is continuous at $0$ - the given counterexample does not have this property.

Comment: Why would we invariably get a function where f(0)=0?

Comment: @user312484 Because you're tracing something, which naturally enforces continuity and hence $f(0)=0$.